# Symfony - how can I render an image from folder (database)

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering, symfony4

I have a table named `products` in the database which contains (`id`, `product-name`, `description`, `delivery-time`, and `photo-name`) .I save only `photo-name` in the database but actual photos are stored in the folder `public->images`. I want to show all data from that table and images from the folder on the screen with Twig but it doesn't show images it only shows this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q67N.png)

This is my twig:

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="my-4">Products:</h2>
                <div style="box-shadow: 2px 3px 9px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);">
                    <div class="q-container-show p-4">
                        {% for wl in wls %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2 text-center">
                                    <img src="{{ asset(wl.getImagePath()) }}" width="100" height="100" alt="photo">
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <div>{{ wl.productname }}</div>
                                        <div>{{ wl.description }}</div>
                                        <div>{{ wl.deliverytime }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my controller:

```
class WelcomeController extends AbstractController{
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome")
 */
public function welcome(ResponseService $responseService)
{

    $wls = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(ProductApplications::class)->findAll();

    if (!$wls) {
        $responseService->responseCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, 'File Not Found');
    }

    return $this->render('default/welcome.html.twig', array('wls' => $wls));
}
```

I know I need to add something in the controller so it can render images from my folder but I'm new to Symfony and I'm not sure what exactly so any help would be appreciated.

Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductApplicationsRepository::class)
 */
class ProductApplications
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=225)
     */
    private $product_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=225)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=225)
     */
    private $deliverytime;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $photoname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":"0"})
     *
     */
    private $sold;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getProductName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->product_name;
    }

    public function setProductName(string $product_name): self
    {
        $this->product_name = $product_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryTime(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliverytime;
    }

    public function setDeliveryTime(string $deliverytime): self
    {
        $this->deliverytime = $deliverytime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getphotoname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photoname;
    }

    public function setphotoname(?string $photoname): self
    {
        $this->photoname = $photoname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getsold()
    {
        return $this->sold;
    }

    public function setsold($sold): self
    {
        $this->sold = $sold;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImagePath()
    {
        return '/public/images/'.$this->getphotoname();
    }
}
```

When I open the path for the image I get this error:

> No route found for "GET /public/images/ordenphoto1.jpg" (from
> "http://localhost/welcome")

Comment: Hi. Can you add the entity code?, the problem might be there. Also, if you debug the path generated for the image, is it correct?

Comment: Can you try removing the first `/` from the `getImagePath` function? So it will look like this `return 'public/images/'.$this->getphotoname();`

Comment: I did that but it's still not working. I think I need to add this image  path somewhere in the controlller so it returns an image from folder but not sure how

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything in the controller as long as the getImagePath() gives you the correct path. Is the image really there? I mean in your project root and then public/images? If it is there you have to have access to it. Could you try finding it and printing it directly in your browser with something like `http://localhost/welcome/public/images/ordenphoto1.jpg`?

Comment: Could you please fix the code markup of the post? It would also be nice if you could share how the HTML displayed by the browser was rendered. You can check it by viewing the page source on the browser.

Comment: when i right click on the one photo in my editor and copy path, the path is: C:\Users\PC\mvc\public\images\ordenphoto1.jpg and when i richt click and chose copy relative path then it is: public\images\ordenphoto1.jpg  And I'm using docker container. I'll add screenshoots in the question

Comment: Then i guess your project is called `MVC`, and your public folder is `public`. If it is so, you should be able to fix the image by changing `return '/public/images/'.$this->getphotoname();` to `return '/images/'.$this->getphotoname();`.

Comment: alexcm Thank you very much. When i deleted public it worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: No problem :) Remember that your project root URL will point at the public folder.